# Product-specific questions that could be general

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are a number of questions appearing that are tagged to some specific RDBMS product even though they could be applicable generally.  The answers that are voted up or accepted are then usually the ones that cover that particular product best, while some helpful souls try to explain how this works in other products.

Examples:

- [Guid vs INT - Which is better as a primary key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264/guid-vs-int-which-is-better-as-a-primary-key)
- [Which collation should I choose for a muiti-language website?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/255/which-collation-should-i-choose-for-a-muiti-language-website)
- [When should I use a unique constraint instead of a unique index?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144/when-to-use-unique-constraint-instead-of-a-unique-index)

Now,

- I could ask an almost identical question again, tagged for another RDBMS, and get an answer that is almost identical in general but with different implementation details.
- I could just leave my answers relevant to other products at the original question, but they will forever have less votes and credibility.
- I could edit and retag the original question, but this might be considered rude and lose some interesting implementation details in the answers.
- Some of these questions might need to be converted to wiki, so that the answers that are best conceptually can be augmented with implementation details for different products by different people.

Opinions?

Answer (score 7):

I vote for reposting the question with it's own tag(s).

- There might be slightly different answers.
- From the search perspective, when users focus on there DBMS they have little chance to the answer if one of their tags is not included.

Reference to parallel queries would be great. Each on can easily decide for himself, if he wants to see them. Otherwise he has to skip some irrelevant answer.

Comment: Agree with this. The simple thing being: "I could ask an almost identical question again, tagged for another RDBMS, and get an answer that is almost identical in general but with different implementation details." - that's exactly what I'd like to learn. I.e. that's working in SO quite nice, like ask how to make a Gallery in iPhone, then ask how to make it in Android - bam, different answers or "implementation details". They are both platforms, right.

Comment: @Sebastian Roth When you know the question for the other platform, you can add links to them to your question and ask explicitly for specific answers

Comment: I concur with "separate implementation details need separate full-blown discussions"